# How include image with a event via eventbrite API

Tags: api, eventbrite

I am trying to post and publish event via eventbrite API but when doing so i cannot upload media to the event.
I managed to get the upload token but don't understand what to do next.

```
def upload_file(filename):
    data = requests.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/media/upload/?type=image-event-logo-preserve-quality&token=__token_here__").json()
    post_args = data['upload_data']
    response = requests.post(data['upload_url'],
        data = post_args,
        files = {
            data['file_parameter_name']: open(filename)   ######error in this line###
        }
    )
    return response, data['upload_token']

ta, tokn = upload_file("C:\\Users\\Nitish\\Desktop\\ERCESS_WORKSPACE\\im.jpg")
```

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 78, in <module>
    ta, tokn = upload_file(r'im.jpg')
  File "test.py", line 55, in upload_file
    data['file_parameter_name']: open(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 504, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
  File "C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 248: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Could you explain further your problem and post some code to get the appropriate help?

Comment: i cant understand the next step how do i upload image from url.
please refer :https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/image-upload

Comment: the above is the code i am using and getting error @HassenCh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary read will be useful because the images videos are stored in binary read mode.
The media files are uploaded in binary mode.